# hibernate @ManyToMany deleting and re-inserting

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have just setup binding of id's from my web forms using spring PropertyEditors and noticed that M:M records are being deleted and re-inserted. At first I thought this was happening because I was using CustomCollectionEditor, but the same is happening with UserEditor.

My domain objects all have equals/hashcode methods that use the primary key and ref if object has not yet been saved.

```
Hibernate: update delivery_team set name=? where id=?
Hibernate: delete from delivery_team_manager where delivery_team_id=?
Hibernate: delete from delivery_team_resource where delivery_team_id=?
Hibernate: insert into delivery_team_manager (delivery_team_id, user_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into delivery_team_manager (delivery_team_id, user_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into delivery_team_manager (delivery_team_id, user_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into delivery_team_manager (delivery_team_id, user_id) values (?, ?)
```

I tried adding a manager using a separate postback and records are not being deleted. so this is clearly not a hibernate issue.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add_manager/{teamid}/{uid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addManager(@PathVariable Long teamid, @PathVariable Long uid, Model model) {
    DeliveryTeam team = deliveryTeamService.getById(teamid);
    User user = userService.loadUserById(uid, false);
    team.getManager().add(user);
    deliveryTeamService.save(team);
    return "redirect:/delivery_team/update/" + teamid;
}
```

Any way I can get binding working well with hibernate? I'de like manager changes to be included in the form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Using the conversion service resolved this issue, since it converts each entity individually rather than the collection itself.